# vb.net How can I pass a reference to a structure from one thread to two other threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Thread 1 fills a structure and then launches thread 2 and 3, which each need a reference to same structure, to work with it.
Can't make copy of structure -- it's big and would take too long BECAUSE the frame arrays within the structure will each be very big -- maybe 25KB each.

Present code gets error when I pass a structure reference to threads 2 and 3 when I start them.

How can I provide thread 2 & 3 with a reference to structure created by thread 1?

THE CODE...

```
        Structure Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure
            dim frame_buffer_index          as integer
            dim board0_frame_array             as Byte()
            dim board1_frame_array             as Byte()
            dim board2_frame_array             as Byte()
            dim need_to_write               as boolean
            dim write_done_flag            as boolean
        end structure

        dim     antenna_frame_buffer as Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure
            ...

    ' ONE THREAD STARTS TWO OTHER THREADS.................
            new_buffer_write_thread = new Thread( AddressOf thread1 )
            new_buffer_write_thread.Start( antenna_frame_buffer )   
            new_buffer_write_thread = new Thread( AddressOf thread2 )
            new_buffer_write_thread.Start( antenna_frame_buffer )   

            ...


    'EACH OF OTHER TWO THREADS NEEDS TO REFERENCE SAME STRUCTURE.....
sub thread1( ByRef antenna_frame_buffer as Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure ) 
            ...
end sub

sub thread2( ByRef antenna_frame_buffer as Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure ) 
            ...
end sub
```

THE ERROR

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be
>   called with these arguments: 'Public Overloads Sub New(start As
>   ThreadStart)': Method 'Public Sub frame_buffer_write_Thread(ByRef
>   antenna_frame_buffer As
>   Embedded_Communication_Interface.Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure)' does
>   not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   ThreadStart()'. 'Public Overloads Sub New(start As
>   ParameterizedThreadStart)': Method 'Public Sub
>   frame_buffer_write_Thread(ByRef antenna_frame_buffer As
>   Embedded_Communication_Interface.Antenna_Frame_Buffer_structure)' does
>   not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub
>   ParameterizedThreadStart(obj As Object)'. SYS HUB and HW GUI
>   C:\PRIMARY\WORK\SYSTEM HUB\SOURCE\Embedded_Communication_Interface.vb
>   1030 Active

Comment: `Present code gets error`  Always tell us the error.

Comment: If this: "Can't make copy of structure -- it's big and would take too long" is true, then you shouldn't be using a structure.  They only make sense when they're small enough to be cheap to copy.

Comment: Also: Your structure as presented isn't large or expensive to copy.  The arrays are reference types and would be shallow-copied.

Comment: If you want to pass a reference, you could create a class instead

Comment: Thanks 'the_lotus'!  That's it!   I will implement forthwith...